# How to create a custom project boilerplate template in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

I am curious if there is a way in the latest android studio version "Giraffe" for example, what is the way to create a new template for creating a full project. I found some information that before there was a directory

```
<installation folder>\plugins\android\lib\templates
```

In which you can build your template, but currently no such thing exists and could not find if it was moved somewhere or if it is even possible with the latest releases. Would love if someone can point me to how I can create my custom templates for whole projects.